# VB 6.0 remove scroll bar from listbox

Tags: vb6

Just wondering if anyone know's how to remove scroll bars from a listbox in VB 6.0? As I want to add a 'global' scroll bar for multiple listboxes. I have searched online, but all of the solutions require the code to be placed in the click event of the list box.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the scrollbars using the Windows API. Here's a sample project to get you started. Add a ListBox (List1) to a form and add the following code:

```
Private Declare Function ShowScrollBar Lib "user32" _ 
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wBar As Long, ByVal bShow As Long) As Long

Private Const SB_VERT = 1

Private Sub HideVertScrollBar(LB As ListBox)
    Call ShowScrollBar(LB.hwnd, SB_VERT, 0&)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 25
        List1.AddItem "Item " & i
    Next

    HideVertScrollBar List1

End Sub

Private Sub List1_Click()

    HideVertScrollBar List1

End Sub
```

If you only call `HideVertScrollBar` in `Form_Load`, when you manually scroll (using the arrow keys), the scrollbar shows up again. We fix this by calling `HideVertScrollBar` in `List1_Click` as well.